# How to stop While loop in R

Tags: r

I write a code to fit weibull distribution and used some loop to calculate initial parameters. But the code takes a long time to run and I want to stop the loop when it exceeds certain time.

```
stime <- Sys.time()            
etime <- Sys.time()

while (abs(QMcb - QM) >= 0.1) {
    if (etime - stime >= 5) {
        next
    }

    b = b - 0.1
    QMcb = b * sqrt(gamma((c+2)/c))

    etime <- Sys.time()
}
```

even when (etime-stime >= 5) = TRUE, the loop still doesn't stop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `break` instead of `next` -

```
while (abs(QMcb - QM) >= 0.1) {
    if (etime - stime >= 5) break   
    b = b - 0.1
    QMcb = b * sqrt(gamma((c+2)/c))    
    etime <- Sys.time()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for `break` not `next`, see `?Control` for more details. Also `etime - stime` will always be a zero as they are defined at the same time.

```
stime <- Sys.time() 
while (TRUE) {
  if (difftime(Sys.time(), stime, units = "secs") >= 5) {
    break()
  } 
  print('Done')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional criteria to your `while` loop which checks for the time elapsed.

```
while (abs(QMcb - QM) >= 0.1 && etime - stime < 5) {
    b <- b - 0.1
    QMcb <- b * sqrt(gamma((c+2)/c))
    etime <- Sys.time()
}
```